# Typeahead removing top padding and width from input field

Tags: jquery, html-framework-7

I'm using Framework7 with jQuery and bootstrap

```
<form class="searchbar">
    <div class="searchbar-inner">
        <div class="searchbar-input-wrap">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search Medicines" id="ahead_search">
            <i class="searchbar-icon"></i>
            <span class="input-clear-button"></span>
        </div>
        <span class="searchbar-disable-button">Cancel</span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Now in app.js whenever I'm selecting the element (tried both noConflict and $ methods)

```
jQuery("#ahead_search").typeahead({....});
```

The look/feel/ui/css/idk what is changing of that input field

I'll include images to show the issue

Before selecting:

[image]

After selecting:

[image]

Not only in framework7 but in almost all cases this is happening.

Comment: Please add all relevant information here in stackoverflow, not in external resources which could move or get removed. Also I for one won't open external links since there is noway of knowing where it will lead. You can add screenshots here from the editor. Also explain what is the problem you are facing, you say "whenever I'm selecting..." but you never say what is happening.

Comment: Uploaded the images using editor's image function

Comment: Please add the code you are using as a [mcve], here on Stack Overflow (you can use the Stack Snippets feature, icon is `<>`). Please do take some time and get it down to the least amount of code possible that recreates the issue; who knows, maybe you'll find the answer while you're doing that. :)

Comment: Almost as if `.typeahead()` removes the `padding-top` from the `.search-bar-info` class. Can you observe any CSS attributes changing in the developer tools (right click -> Inspect -> Styles) for that element?

Comment: Thanks to @C14L , I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: 
Thanks to the comment by [C14L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5520354/c14l), I was able to fix this.
Apparantly, Twitter Typeahead used jquery to append some classes to some elements and also uses inline styling for them
It's the inline style which is getting override by the theme css.
we just need a line in jQuery to prevent that.
So after initialising typeahead,
Just write this

`jQuery('.twitter-typeahead').attr("style", "");`

This will reset the style attribute and revert the input box to it's original.